# c# WCF Service return collection

Tags: c#, arrays, wcf, return

I've created wcf service and everything works correctly but when i try to return Type[] (i got it from Assembly.GetTypes()) i have following exception:

```
    System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. 
---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.IWcfAssembly.GetAssemblyTypes(String a)
   at ConsoleApplication1.ServiceReference1.WcfAssemblyClient.GetAssemblyTypes(String a) in D:\Projekty\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 50
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Projekty\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 17
```

I thought it might be maxItemsInObjectGraph property or maxArrayLenght (and similar) but it didn't help. Still got the same exception. Maybe I did something wrong with the property declaration?

this is my client config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWcfAssembly" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:57040/WcfAssembly.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWcfAssembly" contract="ServiceReference1.IWcfAssembly"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IWcfAssembly" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and this is my service config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWcfAssembly" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="52428899">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I have also added [ServiceBehavior(MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue)] as a class attribute. I had it in my service config before but this is one of tries.

Do you have any ideas guys? Why the array returned from Assembly.GetTypes() causes such error? (big array of int[] works OK)

Comment: I see that type of exceptions if the DataContractSerializer on the serverside can't serialize the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the System.RunTimeType is not serialize (which is in the internal implementation of Type)

using this mock:

```
void Main()
{
    var dto = new MyDto();
    dto.Tada = new Type[] { this.GetType() };
    DataContractSerializer ser =
        new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyDto));

    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    ser.WriteObject(ms, dto);

    ms.Dump();
    dto.Dump();
}

public class MyDto
{
   public Type[]  Tada { get; set; }
}
```

Throws:

> SerializationException: Type 'System.RuntimeType' with data contract
>   name 'RuntimeType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' is
>   not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types
>   not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by
>   using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list
>   of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Which makes sense because RunTimeType is internal (Type itself is abstract). You have to come up with your own serialized type that can convey the info you want.

Comment: I had a feeling that this is the problem and I was afraid of that. I need so much info that it's very hard to serialize it manually. Thank you anyway